# How to get project's data from packages.drupal.org

Tags: composer, community-official-site

Drupal projects can be searched similarly as Packagist:

- https://packages.drupal.org/8/search.json?s=projectname
- https://packagist.org/search.json?q=projectname

From Packagist can be also extrated the project's data (e.g. versions):

- https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony.json

Is it possible to get project's data also from the Drupal repository?

---

More info:

- [Using packages.drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-packagesdrupalorg)
- [Packagist API Documentation](https://packagist.org/apidoc)

Comment: Are you looking for https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/plain/composer.json?

Comment: I look for a way how to get a list of versions (branches and tags) for Drupal projects (modules, themes, core).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Composer documentation on repositories [describes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#provider-includes-and-providers-url) this mechanism, specifically, the `provider-includes` and `providers-url` properties.

These properties describe the package indexes & the URL pattern used for look up, for example:

- https://packages.drupal.org/8/packages.json (root index)
- https://packages.drupal.org/8/drupal/provider-2018-2%24082d3c8e1745428fcd819891137e88683576066b00ed52bd80811943e98e8d08.json (first index)
- https://packages.drupal.org/8/drupal/commerce%24f8b852956418601bb4d985203d4138a18e2bfc0ae1b67b249a667228190fd26f.json (a specific package with all its releases)

Comment: How can I get the hash for a specific Drupal project? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is as follows: I know the project (package) name, e.g. office_hours. I can find the package: https://packages.drupal.org/8/search.json?s=office_hours But there is not the hash.

Comment: Or do I have to search all providers (first indexes) till I find the project and its hash?

Comment: It looks like `https://packagist.org/packages/$VENDOR/$PACKAGE.json` URL pattern is specific to the Packgist host. It doesn't look like that's mandated by Composer (from what I saw). I'm guessing that's just a human-friendly lookup. 

I'd take a look @ the Composer project (https://github.com/composer/composer) to find it's `vendor/package` lookup mechanism so you don't have reinvent the wheel.